# Lang's proof that there exists $x>0$ such that $\cos x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, trigonometry, continuity, proof-explanation

In Undergraduate Analysis on p. 90, Lang assumes the existence of two functions $f$ (sine) and $g$ (cosine) satisfying the conditions $f(0)=0$, $g(0)=1$, $f'=g$ and $g'=-f$. He then goes on to show that there exists $x>0$ such that $\cos x=0$.

With your help, I would like to make some of the steps in his proof more explicit.

> Suppose that no such number exists. Since $\cos$ is continuous, we
> conclude that $\cos x$ cannot be negative for any value $x>0$ (by
> intermediate value theorem). Hence $\sin$ is strictly increasing for
> all $x>0$, and **$\cos x$ is strictly decreasing for all $x>0$**...

It's clear why $\sin$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Why is $\cos$ strictly decreasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$? This would require $\sin x>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. But how can I show this?

> ... Let $a>0$. Then $0<\cos 2a=\cos^2a-\sin^2a<\cos^2a$. By induction,
> we see that $\cos(2^n a)<(\cos a)^{2^n}$ for all positive integers
> $n$. Hence $\cos(2^na)$ approaches $0$ as $n$ becomes large, because
> $0<\cos a<1$. **Since $\cos$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$, it
> follows that $\cos x$ approaches $0$ as $x$ becomes large, and hence
> $\sin x$ approaches $1$.** In particular, there exists a number $b>0$
> such that $$\cos b<\frac{1}{4}\text{ and }\sin b>\frac{1}{2}.$$

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(2^na)=0$ for all $a>0$, how can I conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\cos x=0$? Let $\epsilon>0$. Then I would have to show that there exists $s\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$(\forall x)(x\in(s,\infty)\implies|\cos x|<\epsilon).$$
It's not immediately clear how to find such an $s$. I would have to use the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(2^na)=0$ for all $a>0$, but I don't know how.

Comment: $\cos' = -\sin$

Comment: @copper.hat I think $\cos '=-\sin$ is the hint for showing that $\cos$ is decreasing. Thanks! Any idea how to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\cos x=0$ using $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(2^na)=0$ for all $a>0$?

Comment: Set $a = 1$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos(2^n) = 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \ n \in \mathbb{C} \mid x = 2^n$.

Comment: @TiagoCavalcanteTrindade $\cos(2^n a)$ is a sequence over positive integers not complex numbers. Are you saying that every real number $x$ is equal to $2^n$ for some positive integer $n$?

Comment: If $\sin 0 = 0$ (it does) and $\sin$ is strictly increasing on $x>0$ then $\sin x > 0$ for all $x>0$ and so $\cos$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$ (under the assumptions that will, of course, eventually lead to a contradiction).

Comment: @copper.hat got it, thank you

Comment: $\cos\pi/2=0, \pi/2>0$.

Comment: @markvs At this point, Lang has not defined $\pi$. He is only assuming that $\cos$ and $\sin$ satisfy the conditions I gave above, nothing more.

Comment: I have not seen the book.  Number $\pi$ is studied in the middle school. Derivatives are studied much later. But I can see that in Lang's opinion,  this should be reversed. He was a great mathematician, but his opinions were too strong and sometimes controversial.

Comment: Your claimed $x\to\infty$ limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\cos x>0$ for every $x$, then the sine is strictly increasing. But in the definition it is assumed that $\sin 0=0$. Hence $\sin x>0$ for $x>0$.

And now, the fact that $\cos'x=-\sin x$ tells us that the cosine is strictly decreasing over $(0,\infty)$.

Now you know that $0<\cos x<1$ for every $x>0$: indeed, $\cos x=1$ implies $\sin x=0$, but we have proved that $\sin x>0$ when $x>0$. A bounded and decreasing function has a limit at $\infty$, precisely the infimum of its range (this is known for *every* such function defined over an upper unbounded interval) and in order to find the limit it's sufficient to find the limit over a sequence that has infinite limit. The chosen sequence is $(2^na)$ and it shows that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos x=0
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x=1
$$
using $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ and the fact that the sine is increasing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What theorem allows the passage from limit of a sequence in the domain to the limit over the domain, at infinity? Is it covered in most analysis texts? I would like to see the proof.

Comment: @Vab22 Just use the definition of limit. In general, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=l$ (where both $c$ and $l$ can be infinite) and $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}a_n=c$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=l$.

Answer (score 3):

To the first question : if sine starts from zero and increases, it is positive.
So the derivative of cosine $g'=-f $ is negative.
Hence cosine decreases.

**Added**

To the second question: as cosine starts from $1$ at $x=0$ and decreases, it either reaches zero at some $x_0 > 0$, or not.
So there exists $a$ such that $1 = \cos 0 > \cos a > 0$  (that would be any $a>0$ in the latter case, or some $0<a<x_0$ in the former).
Then, the positive value less than $1$, when raised to a positive power $2^n$, results in decreasing values as $n$ grows (we get a fraction of the same fraction of the fraction, and so on).
However, it never gets negative, as a product of two positive values $(\cos a)^{2^n}\,\cdot\,(\cos a)^2$ makes a positive result.
As a result we get a strictly decreasing positive sequence of cosine's values at $x_n=2^na$.
But we know the function is strictly decreasing, so its values between $x_n<x_{n+1}$ are between $\cos(x_n)$ and $\cos(x_{n+1})$, hence positive, too, and bounded from above by decreasing  $\cos(x_n) = (\cos a)^{2^n}$ as $n$ grows.
This 'squeezes' the cosine towards zero.

I wonder. however, how did author get the identity $$g(2a)=(g(a))^2−(f(a))^2$$ just form the presented assumptions...

Comment: Thank you. Yes now I understand this part. Any suggestions on how to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\cos x=0$?

Comment: @Vab22 Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: Great thank you

Answer (score 2):

The conditions immediately imply that the derivative of $f(x)^2+g(x)^2$ is $0$. So $f(x)^2+g(x)^2=f(0)^2+g(0)^2=1$ for all $x$.

If $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\ge 0$ then  $\forall t>1\,(-f(t)<-f(1)<-f(0)=0)$. But then $$x>1\implies g(x)-g(1)=\int_1^xg'(t)dt=\int_1^x(-f(t))dt<$$ $$<\int_1^x(-f(1))dt=(x-1)(-f(1))\implies$$ $$\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=-\infty$$ contrary to $ g(x)^2=1-f(x)^2\le 1.$

So there must exist $x_1>0$ with $f'(x_1)\le 0.$ And since $f'=g$ is continuous with $f'(0)>0$ there must exist $x_2\in (0,x_1]$ with $0=f'(x_2)=g(x_2).$

Comment: This is a way  clearer solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have gotten to integration yet but I will come back to this once I do.

Comment: @Vab22 . It seems odd to me that an intro to analysis could get to page 90 without covering integration and especially the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which I think has some common elements with @egreg’s answer:

Our functions $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, with $f'=g$, $g'=-f$, so that $f^2+g^2=1$ identically, and $|f|\le1$, $|g|\le1$.

For $g$ to have no zero, it must have a limit, $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\ge0$. There are two cases, positive limit or zero; let me treat the latter case first.

If $\>0=\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}g'(x)=0$ as well, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, contradicting $f^2+g^2=1$.

In case $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=a>0$, then $\forall x, f'(x)\ge a$, and $\forall x\ge0, f(x)\ge ax$ as well, contradicting boundedness of the function $f$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a couple of question. (1) I understand why $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\geq0$ but why must it exist? (2) How can I deduce $f(x)\geq ax$ for all $x\geq 0$ from $f'(x)\geq a$ for all $x>s$ for some $s>0$?

Comment: (1) $g$ is monotone decreasing, bounded below. Completeness of $\Bbb R$ says there’s a limit. (2) Here’s an intermediate statement, corollary of the Law of the Mean for Derivatives: If $F$ is defined for all nonnegative numbers, and $F(0)=0$; and if in addition $F'(x)\ge0$ for all positive $x$, then $F(x)\ge0$ also for all positive $x$. Prove this from the Law of the Mean, then use it to show what you want. (Or, of course, go in one step, without my intermediate proposition. In any case, it depends on the Law of the Mean.)

Answer (score 0):

$n \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow +\infty$ can be interpreted as $n \in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow +\infty$.

In other words, as $n$ approaches positive infinity, we can ignore the negative values.

$\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists \ r \in \mathbb{R} \ \mid \ 2^r = x$

(as $f$ strictly increasing and the statement that is true for integers, it is true for reals, except when $f$ is undefined for a specific number)

$a \ 2^n = 2^{m} \ \mid \ m \in \mathbb{R}$

Therefore $x$ can be written as $a \ 2^n$, then as $s$ gets bigger, the threshold becomes smaller.

Comment: If $x=3$, then there is no $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^r=x$. Are you sure you mean for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $r \approx 1.58496$

Comment: Correct but then $r$ is a real number and not an integer. You've written that for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^r=x$. I think you mean $r\in\mathbb{R}$ instead of $r\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes but $1.58496\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: My mistake, $r \in \mathbb{R}$.